# How to implement Google Googles-like app on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

When I place iPhone camera on an image (Example :Tajmahal),It would show some information of that image(Tajmahal) like it's history,Where it is located.....etc.This could be done in  iPhone app.Kindly help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know Why some body given -1 .If I have done any mistake,tell me.Just I want to correct it.

Comment: try to be a bit more specific with your question, what exactly is it that you are trying to do? Adding code always helps.

Comment: @sri the reason you have downvotes from some people is that you are asking how to implement a very complicated system that will be very difficult and expensive to build. They might assume that because of the way you asked the question, you would not be able to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Okay.

1 - you need to take a picture with the camera

2 - you need to write an API on a server which can do feature recognition, and identify that this is the Taj Mahal. This will require crawling the web for images, and also identifying what the image contains, and collating this with other data available on the web.

3 - You need to submit the image to the API from your iPhone app

4 - You need to display this on screen.

The difficult bit is step 2. To do this, you need to be Google or Microsoft so you have the developer resources, computing resources and money to construct the service. Alternatively, convince a company such as Google to release an API to a service such Google Goggles.

Or, tell your user to download and use the Google Goggles app.